# Clear ET Triggered Send Queue

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does anyone know if there is a way to clear a queue for a triggered send that is paused? We have a message that has been paused for some time that will no longer be relevant for those recipients that have been queued up. There does not seem to be any option for this through the UI, maybe support can clear from the back end?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

You would want to reach out to help@exacttarget.com and the support team can have have that taken care of for you.  They would need to know the MID, Name, and External Key of the triggered send needed to be cleared.

Hope that helps!  Thanks!